# About Json Syntax

Tags: android, json

I am very frustrated with the Json syntax of JsonObject and JsonArray after reading some posts
This is the Json that return from my localhost
[{"Age":18},{"Age":18},{"Age":18}]

Is it a Json Array containing 3 objects?

I want to make in as a string in eclispe

```
private String strJSONValue1 = {"Age":18},{"Age":18},{"Age":18} but it have errors.
```

This is the demo code in the project

```
 private String strJSONValue1 ={"FirstObject": { "attr1":"one value" ,"attr2":"two  value",   
 "sub": { "sub1":[ {"sub1_attr":"sub1_attr_value" },{"sub1_attr":"sub2_attr_value"   }]}   
}   
}
```

I would like to clarify the differences, and should I include the [] that means a array?

Comment: JSON only works natively in Javascript.  In everything else, it has to be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have single object at the root:  {}, [], "Some String", double, integer.  Of course Object ({}) or Array ([]) are really the only options that make sense because they can contain many other types of objects than String, double, or integer, but could can have them.

```
{"Age":18},{"Age":18},{"Age":18}
```

That is three objects at the root so its not valid.  If you wanted a collection of 3 items you'd need to do:

```
[ {"Age":18},{"Age":18},{"Age":18} ]
```

Comment: Thank you . I would like to hardcode the string to test the code whether it can output my Json or not. Then I would try to connect it from the URL. THX

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your String in quotes (and escape any inner quotes) as follows.  Your also missing the outer braces [].

```
private String strJSONValue1 = "[ {\"Age\":18},{\"Age\":18},{\"Age\":18} ]"
```

Comment: Thank you . I would like to hardcode the string to test the code whether it can output my Json or not. Then I would try to connect it from the URL. THX

Comment: Or use single quote ' instead of " then you don't have to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

`[]` notation is for defining arrays. if you have something like this ;

```
 { "Ages" : [ {"Age":18}, {"Age":18}, {"Age":18} ] }
```

then you can get the json array by `getJSONArray("Ages")` method with parameter "Ages"